# canvas toDataURL with background image

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas element that I want to allow the user to download as an image. I have managed to get SVG to download however I was wondering if there was any way to include the canvas css background image to download with it?

EDIT:

I have realised that what I am actually looking for is a workaround for the following from http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/;

> The toDataURL() method requires that any images drawn onto the canvas are hosted on a web server with the same domain as the code executing it.  If this condition is not met, a SECURITY_ERR exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the full URL of the canvas background image and draw it on a new canvas, then use the first canvas as a parameter of `drawImage` to draw its content onto the second canvas

Comment: I will give this a go. I tried something similar previously and the fact the I mixed sources meant that the canvas was no longer able to be saved locally.

Comment: This will still be a problem, if the background image is not hosted on the same domain ... you can stil draw it onto the canvas, but you won't be able to use `toDataURL()` on it